# List all sub-sequences of an integer

Tags: list-manipulation

Need some help listing all sub-sequences of a number:

```
X=219
```

The output should be:

> {2,21,219,1,19,9}

Order does not matter for this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a combination of [`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html) + [`Subsequences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsequences.html) + [`FromDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html):

```
FromDigits /@ Rest @ Subsequences[IntegerDigits @ #] & @ 219
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 9, 21, 19, 219}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
X = 219;

FromDigits /@ ReplaceList[IntegerDigits[X], {___, x__, ___} -> {x}]
```

> {2, 21, 219, 1, 19, 9}

Answer (score 3):

```
X = 219; 
Y = IntegerDigits[X]; 
FromDigits /@(Y[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] & /@
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, Length[Y]}, {j, i, Length[Y]}], 1])
```

gives

```
{2, 21, 219, 1, 19, 9}
```

Note that

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, Length[Y]}, {j, i, Length[Y]}], 1]
```

is

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
```

the set of pairs of starting position and ending position.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subsets[IntegerDigits@219, {1, 3}]
```

gives

```
{{2}, {1}, {9}, {2, 1}, {2, 9}, {1, 9}, {2, 1, 9}}
```

If you do not want the three-length set, then use

```
Subsets[IntegerDigits@219, {1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceCases` with its `All`- option

```
SequenceCases[IntegerDigits[219], x : {__} :> FromDigits[x], Overlaps -> All]
```

{219, 21, 2, 19, 1, 9}

Answer (score 3):

Using `Sequences`:

```
ToExpression["" <> ## & @@@ Subsequences[Characters@ToString@219, {1, 3}]]

(*{2, 1, 9, 21, 19, 219}*)
```